# Regex to get 2 digit-numbers not immediately preceded and followed by a character in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regex in Java that gets all two digit numbers (two digit number cannot start with 0) and it not preceded by and followed by a character.

For instance, I want to match the number 30 in the following strings:

- character30 wordstart
- wordstart 30character
- the number 30 is here

But do not want to on the following:

- character30character
- 3000

I am trying to use look arounds to accomplish this and the closest I have come so far is:
`(?<!\w)(1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9])(?!([\w]))`

The two digit number cannot start with 0 and I do not want to match 2 digit numbers within a three digits number.

Comment: What about [`\b\d{2}|\d{2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/4VgGMU/1)?

Comment: Let know if it worked or not. The question like this can be answered differently. If you require whitespaces at least at one of the word boundaries, you will need `(?<!\S)\d{2}(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\S)`.

Comment: Another idea is to match two digit sequences inside letters and capture others: `\p{L}\d{2}\p{L}|(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)`

Comment: Hey Wiktor, there were a couple more conditions that I forgot to mention, as  in the two digit number cannot start with 0 and I do not want to match 2 digit numbers within a three digits number. However, your second answer gave me enough of a base to create a regex that I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(?<!\S)[1-9]\d(?!\d)|(?<!\d)[1-9]\d(?!\S)
```

Remember to double backslashes when defining the regex pattern in Java string literals.

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` - the next digit must be preceded with whitespace or start of string
- `[1-9]\d` - a digit from 1 to 9 and then any one digit
- `(?!\d)` - the two digits cannot be followed with another digit
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\d)` - there cannot be a digit right before the...
- `[1-9]\d` - digit from 1 to 9 and then any one digit
- `(?!\S)` - that should be followed with a whitespace or end of string.

Answer (score 0):

The following code simply tests Wiktor's comment in Java:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestIt
{
    public static void main (String args[])
        throws Exception
    {
        String test1 = "character30 wordstart";
        String test2 = "wordstart 30character";
        String test3 = "the number 30 is here";

        String failTest = "character30character";

        String regex = "\\b\\d{2}|\\d{2}\\b";

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher match = pat.matcher(test1);
        System.out.println("test1: " + match.find());
        match = pat.matcher(test2);
        System.out.println("test2: " + match.find());
        match = pat.matcher(test3);
        System.out.println("test3: " + match.find());
        match = pat.matcher(failTest);
        System.out.println("failTest: " + match.find());
    }
}
```

With results:

```
test1: true
test2: true
test3: true
failTest: false
```